# Chromatic number of 2-graph vs hypergraph of point-line incidences

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, graph-colorings, hypergraph

Define the chromatic number $\chi(H)$ of a (hyper)graph $H$ as the smallest $k$ such that its vertices can be $k$-colored such that no (hyper)edge is monochromatic.
Given a finite set of points $P$ in the plane, consider the hypergraph $H(P)$ on the vertex set $P$ such that $E\subset P$ is a hyperedge if $|E|\ge 2$ and there is a line $\ell$ such that $\ell\cap P=E$.
Define the graph $G(P)$ as the restriction of $H(P)$ to its edges of size 2.

> By what function of $\chi(G(P))$ can we bound $\chi(H(P))$ from above?

Note: The [dual of this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439177/chromatic-number-of-a-dual-graph-of-straight-lines) was asked by a [new and anonymous user](https://mathoverflow.net/users/496369/causalityrefilm) 2 days ago, who shortly afterwards deleted it.

Comment: You mean, these are points and lines on the usual Euclidean plane?

Comment: I am confused. Is not it true that $\chi(H)\leqslant \chi(G)$ - of course, if all edges have at least two vertices - by using the same coloring?

Comment: or you mean that the edges of $H$ are not collinear sets, but only inclusion-maximal?

Comment: @Fedor I'm sorry, what I wrote first made little sense. I hope now it's ok.